# drupal 7 webform form elements not displaying

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I have created a new content (web form).

I have successfully added some elements using webform. But it's not displaying form elements on view page.

Can anyone help me in this matter ?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that your theme is not printing out that content? Try using the default theme and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with drupal 6. Later, I found a couple of problems. 
I forgot to run update.php file when I upgraded from 3.5 to 3.12 version. 
Also, do not forget to flush cache. After doing these two tasks, it worked as expected. May be, same is applicable for Drupal 7.